# Find the remainder when the number $52^{1989}$ is divided by 7.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find the remainder when the number $52^{1989}$ is divided by 7.

I tried arithmetic modular, but seems didn't work

Comment: you know that $52\equiv 3\mod 7$. Also, you can use the Euler-Fermat theorem, wich (in this case) says that $3^6\equiv 1\mod 7$, so in the exponent, you may work modulo $6$.

Comment: @Ragnar If you make that an answer (and ping me), I'll upvote.

Comment: @anorton done :)

Answer (score 3):

$52\equiv 3\bmod 7$, by [fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermats_little_theorem)  $3^6\equiv 1 \bmod7$, therefore $52^{1989}\equiv 3^{1989}=3^{1986}*3^3=3^{331*6}*3^3\equiv1*3^3\equiv6$

Answer (score 2):

You know that $52\equiv3\mod7$. Also, you can use the Euler-Fermat theorem, wich (in this case) says that $36\equiv1\mod7$, so in the exponent, you may work modulo $6$.
In general, Euler-Fermat says that $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\mod m$, and here $m$ is prime, so $\phi(m)=p-1$.
This is only true when $\gcd(a,m)=1$ (i.e. they are relative prime), because otherwise, a power of $a$ can never be $1\mod m$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 7\!:\ 52^{3n} \equiv 3^{3n}\equiv (3^3)^n\equiv (-1)^{n} \equiv -1\ $ for odd $\rm\,n.\,$ (Here $\rm\,1989 = 3\cdot 663 = 3n).$